# Find the email aliases a message was actually sent to

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there a way to get the email aliases address to which an email was originally sent from Microsoft Graph?

We have a single email account like `main@company.com` along with the multiple other associated email addresses (email aliases). Emails send to any of the aliases go to a to the same inbox as `main@company.com`.

If we send an email to `alias@company.com` and look at the message using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`, it shows `mail@company.com` as the email address. We need to detect if it was sent to `alias@company.com`.

The information for the allies can be found in the email header and there is a potential workaround in the Outlook API:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/{messageId}?$select=Subject,SingleValueExtendedProperties &$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x7D')
```

This returns an unstructured result which needs to be parsed and it is not very convenient. We are looking if there is a more direct way to get this from Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `$filter` with Microsoft Graph. You simply need to switch `PropertyId` to simply `id`:

```
?$select=subject&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x7D')
```

Also note that don't need to both `select` and `expand` the `singleValueExtendedProperties` collection. Expanding will ensure it gets included.

Comment: We tried this earlier, but it didn't return the mail sent to field. It returns only a subset of what we can get using the outlook call with $filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x7D' parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, we are able to get a string back which has the original to email address - it seems the same result as from the outlook. Is this the only way to get the aliases?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: What exactly does 'String 0x7D' mean in this case?

Comment: It's the id of the property you want to retrieve.